# What does "review item not found" mean?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

In the recent [3D printing SE](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/), I  often get this in the review queues.

> [image]

So, what does this mean?  Is the post removed, or something else?

I don't think it would be post removal, as it is happening very often on both the close votes and reopen votes queues.

Comment: I can reproduce this. Can't currently load *any* review items in any queues on 3D Printing unless I go to them manually with a URL.

Comment: @animuson Just wanted to know, when does the `review item not found` message be displayed in the review queues?

Comment: I've never seen it before. I imagine it might've been a quick-fix to another problem the queues were experiencing earlier where they were timing out after loading for a while. No idea though.

Comment: @animuson It seems like an issue with the validation - I keep getting it whenever I try to review close votes from the Review page.

Comment: @animuson any chance it's related to the site being at private beta?

Comment: @Shadow Shouldn't be an issue. I've reviewed things on private betas before, and there are other reviews recorded from before it broke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a mildly annoying bug.  Apparently we have never launched a site that contained a number in a host name.  In review we had this javascript code to parse out the review task:

```
matches = document.URL.match(/\/\d+/g);
```

Anyone want to guess what that returns for a url of:  https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/close

[image: sigh]

A fix has rolled out.